# can anyone guide me to create another menu in this code?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, menu, dropdown

```
This is the codepen link : https://codepen.io/creotip/pen/zbBig/
```

In this code how to create multiple menu? currently only one menu (collection) there, need two more menus,i am unable to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your .navbar-nav div into a flexbox container and you're good to go. I implemented that in this codepen link: https://codepen.io/bolajiayeni/pen/JjGNbMG

```
.navbar-nav {
  display: flex;  
}
```

Hope this helps!